# A command to download a file other than Wget

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, wget

My host allows limited access to SSH and Linux commands. However, I can't use [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) believe it or not.

I was hoping for something to download a file (.flv) from another server. Is there another command I can try?

If there isn't, I could probably make use of Python, Perl or PHP (favourite) to achieve a file download. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you explain why you can't use wget?

Comment: I've seen that before; some sysadmins will actually block it out of a belief that not having access to it is "more secure". There may be other reasons, but that's the one I usually see.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the following command:

`curl -O http://www.domain.com/file.flv`

Comment: Why did the OP accept this answer? Many others mentioned curl a long ago and to top it all off the exact command given here is incorrect. Bizarre.

Comment: Hi,
You should read: man curl. -o means writing output file to disk instead of giving it to stdout. :)

Comment: gotta encourage newbies!

Comment: Saving you trouble, paste from the man page under -O: "Write output to a local file named like the remote file we get." This is what the OP asked for and it's puzzling to me why you think it is incorrect. Also I tested it and it behaves as expected.

Comment: works for me....

Answer (score 9):

```
echo -ne "GET /path/to/file HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.somesite.com\r\n\r\n" | nc www.somesite.com 80 | perl -pe 'BEGIN { while (<>) { last if $_ eq "\r\n"; } }'
```

Comment: This is clearly epic, but it seems to run and provide no feedback.

Comment: I never said it was a very /good/ option. But if you've got netcat and perl... (though, using LWP::Simple would probably be better if you have perl. this could be changed to use sed or awk or something instead easily enough though)

Comment: you can theoreticaly do it without netcat and without perl -- bash has tcp redirections and sed can erase the header. But i realy don't feel like writing it :-) look here: http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2006/05/23/bash-socket-programming-with-devtcp-2/

Comment: GNU awk has TCP redirections too :)  @cube: I didn't see your comment when I wrote my answer below, but that's pretty much the same as what I did.

Comment: @cube, a number of distributions (including debian) disable bash tcp redirections - after all, that's stealing part of the filesystem namespace

Comment: @bdonlan: Or for security or size or something like that, more likely.  It's not like "stealing" `/dev/{tcp,udp}/*/*` matters when there's no devices with those names.

Answer (score 6):

```
curl -C - -O http://www.url.com
```

Answer (score 6):

[Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) compiled with `--enable-net-redirections` is pretty powerful.  ([Zsh](http://www.zsh.org/) has similar features.)  Heck, I'll even throw HTTP Basic Auth in here, too.

Of course, it's not a very good HTTP/1.1 client; it doesn't support chunked encoding, for example.  But that's pretty rare in practice.

```
read_http() {
    local url host path login port
    url="${1#http://}"
    host="${url%%/*}"
    path="${url#${host}}"
    login="${host%${host#*@}}"
    host="${host#${login}@}"
    port="${host#${host%:*}}"
    host="${host%:${port}}"
    (
        exec 3<>"/dev/tcp/${host}/${port:-80}" || exit $?
        >&3 echo -n "GET ${path:-/} HTTP/1.1"$'\r\n'
        >&3 echo -n "Host: ${host}"$'\r\n'
        [[ -n ${login} ]] &&
        >&3 echo -n "Authorization: Basic $(uuencode <<<"${login}")"$'\r\n'
        >&3 echo -n $'\r\n'
        while read line <&3; do
            line="${line%$'\r'}"
            echo "${line}" >&2
            [[ -z ${line} ]] && break
        done
        dd <&3
    )
}
```

OTOH, if you have Perl's [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP) installed, it should ship with a sample binary named [GET](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP)…

Answer (score 5):

`lynx -source`

Answer (score 5):

Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os,sys,urllib
f = open (os.path.basename (sys.argv[1]), 'w')
f.write (urllib.urlopen (sys.argv[1]).read ())
f.close ()
```

where `sys.argv[1]` is the URL you're interested in.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to download a file from a host you have authenticated access to, try using `scp`. It's like a normal copy but it is done through an ssh tunnel. I've found that hosts who allow "limited ssh" often still allow `scp`.

```
scp user@myhost.com:folder/file.flv ./
```

You will need to provide your user credentials. See [`scp` documentation](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/scp.1.php) for more information.

Comment: Abs clearly states it's from another server.

Comment: @Randolpho - ummm, scp allows you to copy from another server.  It's scp's sole function.

Comment: @sheepsimulator: you can only use SCP if you have *access* to the remote server, i.e. it's a host on which you have an account. I believe Abs does not have such. That said, on a second read of the question it could be interpreted that Abs has access to the remote host. Based on that, I'm rescinding my downvote.

Comment: @Randolpho, I found the question to be rather ambiguous as to whether he had authenticated access or not. I just gave my two-cents. Thanks for removing the downvote anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

Another tool that's out there that does similar stuff is [snarf](http://www.xach.com/snarf/).

Answer (score 2):

Various ways,

- Perl -- [File::Fetch](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Fetch.html) module
- TCL -- [::http::geturl](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/http.htm), has example at the end
- If you have the compiler and FTP works, [get wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) and compile it

Answer (score 1):

Another possible alternative is [aria2](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

Use scp.

> usage: scp [-1246BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file] 
>              [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
>              [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2